# Why is my attributed convert string to number in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a form where users can enter a duration as string like "08:00" or "3:10". My idea was to convert this to the correct amount of seconds in a `before_validation` callback.

But somehow Rails does something before the callback as the value is always `"0"` when an user entered `"08:00"` or `"3"` when an user entered `"3:10"`.

Nothing snooty is happening in my form;

```
<%= f.text_field :duration, required: true, class: 'input' %>
```

in my controller;

```
def create
  @entry = Entry.new entry_params
end

private 

def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:date, :duration, :project_id)
end
```

Or in my model;

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project

  validates :duration, presence: true

  before_validation :normalize_duration

  def duration_formatted(format = '%H:%M')
    Time.at(duration).utc.strftime format
  end

  private

  def normalize_duration
    # Always receiving the first character here :(
    p self.inspect
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the type of your `duration` column? Integer?

Comment: Yes it's indeed of type integer

Comment: Well, that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite the def duration=(value) method, which is generated by active record.
Instead of using before validation, you have to do something like this:

```
    def duration=(value)
      seconds = Time.parse(value).utc.to_i - Time.parse("00:00").utc.to_i

      self[:duration] = seconds
    end
```

Comment: Thanks! The setter bit of the answer worked, the parsing of the value didn't. But I did that one myself through splitting the string and converting it back to integers.

Comment: And you'll have to do `super seconds`, otherwise you'll run into an infinite loop.

Comment: @robinvdvleuten just do like this self[:duration]. Weird. The parser worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want to do is to compare the entered `duration` with the "zero-th time" (`0:00`).  Then you can extract an *elapsed time in seconds* based on the user's input of `duration`:

```
def duration_in_seconds
  Time.parse(duration).utc.to_i - Time.parse("00:00").utc.to_i
end
```